# Downloading a 20GB directory from a server

Tags: backup

I have to get a 20GB directory from my server to my desktop. It has probably millions of files, and I can't tgz them because for some reason it won't write the file past 7.5GB. What's the best way to get the files down? I need something better than FTP because that will take ages with so many files. Will I not have the 7.5GB file limit if I skip gz?

Comment: What operating systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It has probably millions of files, and I can't tgz them because for some reason it won't write the file past 7.5GB.

You can tgz them, just not write them down on the server:

```
ssh you@your.server "tar zcvf - /directory/with/millions/of/files" > millions-of-files.tar.gz
```

I'm assuming you have ssh access if you were considering tgz in the first place.

Comment: I ended up using zip and it worked fine, but I would have gone with this had I seen it.

Answer (score 1):

Something better than FTP? Using a different protocol is not going to reduce the number of files you have. rsync over ssh using tar gz seems like it would work best.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are on the right track, but I'd recommend creating a multiple part compressed file, and then transfer the directory using your file transfer method of choice.

This way you can transfer many of these files in parellel, giving for a much faster completion, depending on your network connection of course.

See the question:

> How can I create multipart tar file in Linux?
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/198857/how-can-i-create-multipart-tar-file-in-linux

Also, I was assuming you were using Linux. But if you are not, WinRAR can easily do this on Windows. Then transfer using NFS or whatever you prefer.